# WPF: Accessing the DataContext's "DataTemplate"

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, datacontext, itemscontrol

I have a `ListBox` which is populated by `ItemsSource` (`ObservableCollection<MyClass>`). If I have the reference of a particular `ListBoxItem`, I can easily find its data object through `DataContext`, which will give me the matching `MyClass` object.

Now, I want to reverse this. I want to get the `ListBoxItem` that a particular instance of `MyClass` object is represented by. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: For me personaly the quesion is unclear.
Could you add code segments with explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ContainerFromItem` method of the ListBox's `ItemContainerGenerator`:

```
MyClass item = ...
var listBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
```

Comment: I tried it on a plain `ItemsControl`, it gave me a plain `ContentPresenter`, which has the `MyClass` in its `Content` property. Do you know how to change this default "container" for custom `ItemsControl`s?

Comment: You'll  have to derive from ItemsControl (or ListBox, etc) and overide the [GetContainerForItemOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.getcontainerforitemoverride(v=vs.110).aspx) method.